# Add css class to parent li and sub li

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parent

I have a submenu like below:

```
<ul id="main-menu" class="" style="">
<li class="root-level has-sub">
    <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
<li class="root-level has-sub"> <!-- here -->
    <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
        <li class="root-level has-sub"> <!-- add class 'opened' here and -->
            <a href="#">Sub-menu 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-sub-Menu 1</a></li> <!-- this -->
                <li><a href="#">Sub-sub-Menu 2</a></li> <!-- when user click this or -->
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

What I would like to have is, when I click to the child, it will add 'opened' class to parent and highlight the clicked element. My code only success on Menu 1 and failed on Menu 3.

Notice that, in Menu 3, there are 2 parents for Sub-sub-Menu 1 and Sub-sub-Menu 2. So my question is, if i click on Sub-sub-Menu 1 or Sub-sub-Menu 2 it will highlight and add 'opened' class to 2 parents li above.

Note: I try to implement unlimited level of menu

Here is my full code [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/softboxkid/GEj4z/3/)

Comment: is it that way you want ? http://jsfiddle.net/GEj4z/4/

Comment: not exactly. your code just have 1 parent and 2 child. mine is parent>parent>childs, see my code on posted jsfiddle hyperlink above.

Comment: i hope it is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a different selector(for the `click` event). Look for all `li>a` pairs, corresponding to the submenu items, inside your `#main-menu` list

```
$('#main-menu li>a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.opened').removeClass('opened'); 
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').parents('.root-level').addClass('opened');
//------------------------------------------------------^-----------------------------
//                                  selects all parents with the 'root-level' class
});
```

Modifying the css to:

```
#main-menu .active {
    background-color:#df0000;
    color:#fff;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/GEj4z/19/)

Answer (score 1):

you simply use the `not:` attribute in your `closest()` method to exclude all classes `root-level`

```
$(function () {

    $('ul#main-menu li ul li').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //we search for the first ancestor of this which is a li
        $(this).closest('li:not(".root-level")').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        $('.active:first').closest('ul').addClass('opened');

    });

});
```

check the link http://jsfiddle.net/GEj4z/11/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what was desired was being able to produce a menu like behavior and it is because of that I would like to present an alternate solution:

[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GEj4z/13/)

```
$('#main-menu').on('click','li:not(.root-level)',function(e){
        $('.parent').removeClass('parent');
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');


            $(this).parents('li.root-level').children('a').addClass('parent');
            $(this).children('a').addClass('selected');            
    });
```

In this solution the parent menus are highlighted and the clicked item is marked as selected again I wanted to share my POV of this problem. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your click event use $(this).parents('li') to get the top level parent li of the clicked element. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! my jquery is:

```
$(function () {

$('ul#main-menu li ul li').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('li:not(".root-level")').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    $(this).parents('li').addClass('opened');
    $(this).closest('li:has(".root-level")').removeClass('active');
});

});
```

Here is my full code [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/softboxkid/GEj4z/23/)